# Trying to convert powershell script to VBscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript, conditional-statements

Figured it out with the help of Lee_Dailey & js2010! Thanks fellas!

**EDIT**
I am trying to figure out why I get a false positive when it's deployed through SCCM to a collection of computers. I get devices Non-Compliant when in fact they are. I was asked to provide the VB version of the script by the SCCM operators. I'm crossing off the potential causes.

I am trying to convert the functionality of a PowerShell script to VBScript. The script checks for the AzureAdPrt token on a device but the challenge is with the output of that command, since it is formatted in a table and I only want to check a specific value.

I attempted to replicate the technology to VBScript but I have no experience with it.

Powershell Code:

```
    $dsregcmd = dsregcmd /status
    $PRTDetails = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $dsregcmd | Select-String -Pattern " *[A-z]+ : [A-z]+ *" | ForEach-Object {
              Add-Member -InputObject $PRTDetails -MemberType NoteProperty -Name (([String]$_).Trim() -split " : ")[0] -Value (([String]$_).Trim() -split " : ")[1]
         }
$PRT_Status = ($PRTDetails).AzureAdPrt
IF($PRT_Status -eq 'YES'){
    return $True
}ELSE{
    return $False
}
```

VB Code:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /c dsregcmd /status"
IF oShell = "AzureAdPrt : YES"
  echo $true
ELSE
  echo $false
```

What I am looking for is the VBScript to return $true if AzureAdPrt equals YES and $False if it's not.

Comment: you will need to parse the output of  `dsregcmd`. right now your code does a comparison with the _entire_ output, not the part you care about. so ... capture that output to a $Var, study the pattern, and apply that in your VBScript code.

Comment: why are you doing this? if nothing else, VBScript can call PoSh. but i suspect you are solving a problem caused by another problem. what is the reasoning behind your question?

Comment: Is there some reason you want to convert this to VBS instead of just leaving in as PS? My experience is that PS is often more flexible and less "awkward" in code than VBS, and MS is strongly advocating conversion of VBS to PS, rather than the reverse.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Thanks for the tip! I prefer PS but I am trying to figure out why I get a false positive when it's deployed through SCCM to a collection of computers. I get devices Non-Compliant when in fact they are. I was asked to provide the VB version of the script by the SCCM operators. I'm crossing off the potential causes.

Comment: regex in vbscript:  https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_regexp.php

Comment: @Azdamus - thank you for the feedback. [*grin*] you may want to add that to your Original Post so that you don't get asked the same question again & again ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - I find proper feedback to be of huge value. I will edit the post. I'm sorry I cannot mark it as solved due to the demotes. Thanks again!
js2010 - Thanks for the link. That also helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that with vbscript : [Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/3t1XiB/1)

```
Option Explicit
Dim oShell,Data,Extracted_Data
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /c dsregcmd /status > .\AzureLog.txt",0,True
Data = ReadFile(".\AzureLog.txt")
wscript.echo Data
Extracted_Data = Extract(Data)

IF Extracted_Data = "AzureAdPrt : YES" Then
    wscript.echo Extracted_Data & vbCrlf & "True"
Else
    wscript.echo Extracted_Data & vbCrlf & "False"
End If

'---------------------------------------------------------------
Function ReadFile(path)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim objFSO,objFile
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path,ForReading)
    ReadFile = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
End Function
'---------------------------------------------------------------
Function Extract(Data)
    Dim RegEx,Match,Matches,M
    Set RegEx = New RegExp
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "\bAzureAdPrt : \w+"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(Data)
    'Iterate through the Matches collection.
    For Each Match in Matches
        'We only want the first match.
        M = Match.Value
        Exit For
    Next
    Extract = M
    'Clean up
    Set Match = Nothing
    Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
'---------------------------------------------------------------
```